# how to optimize this awk script?

Tags: awk

I browse 2 files with awk. I browse the first file and store the columns I need in arrays. I use after these arrays to make a comparison with a column (8) of the second file.
my script runs very slowly. I would like to know if there is not a way to optimize it?

```
FNR==NR
{
    a[$1];
    ip[NR]=$1;
    site[NR]=$2;
    next
}


BEGIN{

FS="[\t,=]";
OFS="|";

}

sudo awk -f{
l=length(ip);

if($8 in a)
{
    for(k=0;k<=l;k++)
   {
     if(ip[k]== $8)
     {

      if(NF <= 70)
         {
           print  "siteID Ipam: "site[k],"siteID zsc: "$14,"date: " $4,"src: "$8,"dst: "$10,"role: "$22,"urlcategory: "$36, "urlsupercategory: "$38,"urlclass: "$40;
          }
      else
         {
           print "siteID Ipam: "site[k], "siteID zsc: "$14,"date: " $4, "src: " $8, "dst: " $10, "role: "$22, "urlcategory: " $37, "urlsupercategory: "$39, "urlclass: $41;
         }
      break;
     }
   }
}
else
{
print $8 " is not in referentiel ";
}
}
```

Comment: `sudo awk -f` inside the code doesn't make sense. Please add 2 very small sample input files, and then show how the command should be run. You'll also have to give us some real numbers for what you mean by "real slow" i.e. "I have 10,000 recs and 2,000 recs, and it is taking 4 hours to process" or whatever your real case is. Good luck.

Comment: I believe you have a typo with `sudo awk -f` in your code.

Comment: FWIW: `sudo awk -f` is taking the value of the uninitialized variable `sudo` and concatenating it with the result of subtracting the value of the uninitialized variable `f` from the value of the uninitialized variable `awk` with the end result being the string `"0"` which is non-null and so the associated action block is co-incidentally executed. If you removed the `sudo` then the final operation would not be concatenation and so the result would be the number `0` instead of the string `"0"` and then the action block would **not** be executed.

Comment: The performance issue is you unnecessarily looping through all elements if `ip` looking for a match. Fix the syntax errors in your script (no, not the sudo... stuff - the actual **syntax errors** that are causing it to fail to run with a syntax error output message) and post some concise, testable sample input and expected output if you'd like more help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better formatted same code with the initial typo.

```
BEGIN {
    FS = "[\t,=]";
    OFS = "|";
}
FNR == NR {
    a[$1];
    ip[NR] = $1;
    site[NR] = $2;
    next;
}
sudo awk -f {
    l = length(ip);

    if($8 in a) {
        for(k = 0; k <= l; k++) {
            if(ip[k] == $8) {
                if(NF <= 70) {
                    print  "siteID Ipam: "site[k],"siteID zsc: "$14,"date: " $4,"src: "$8,"dst: "$10,"role: "$22,"urlcategory: "$36, "urlsupercategory: "$38,"urlclass: "$40;
                }
                else {
                    print "siteID Ipam: "site[k], "siteID zsc: "$14,"date: " $4, "src: " $8, "dst: " $10, "role: "$22, "urlcategory: " $37, "urlsupercategory: "$39, "urlclass: $41;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        print $8 " is not in referentiel ";
    }
}
```

suggest:

1. fix `sudo awk -f` typo.
2. `a[$1];` -->  `a[$1] = 1;`
3. `($8 in a)` --> `(a[$8])`

Comment: The first suggestion is valid but won't actually affect the execution of the code and the other 2 suggestions are actually wrong in as much as they won't change the behavior but they will use a bit more memory.